# Different use of .yaml and .toml file

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment, eris-industries, configuration

I started learning Eris chain and in the deploying section, they use [.yaml file](https://monax.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#step-3-2-fixup-your-epm-yaml) and for making the chain definition file they use [.toml file](https://monax.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#step-2-a-1-make-or-get-the-public-keys). I searched the internet and what I found was they both are configuration files. So why not use only 1 file type.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is directly related to Ethereum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prior answer regarding the file types is correct.

1. The TOML format is simpler and is used throughout Eris (Monax) configuration files, e.g. chain configuration or docker image versions (~/.eris/eris.toml).
2. The YAML format supports the complexity better that is needed to define the "jobs" that are run be the package manager (EPM) for contract deployment and contract invocation.

One correction regarding FrenchieiSverige's answer above: The Eris blockchain is a permissioned blockchain design and it uses Tendermint's POS consensus instead Ethereum's POW, so there is no *mining* happening on the validator nodes. Ether still exists and can be assigned via administrators, but it is typically not used as a value token.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to different types of configuration files because:

- `.yaml` file is to configure the smart contracts
- `.toml` file is to configure the blockchain itself with the `genesis.json` file.

Once the blockchain is running, you can create a miner, and start doploying your smart contracts using the Ether you just mined with your miner.